# Opengl ES texture rendering concept

Tags: opengl-es, 2d, textures

I am planning to write a simple 2D platformer in Javascript where each frame will be drawn with different (textured) tiles. Here are my questions:

- How do I render different rectangles / quads with different textures? I mean do I write a separate fragment shader for rock tiles and grass tiles, and do I keep the vertex data for each type of tile in a separate buffer? I want to put all my tile vertex data in one buffer, but how do I specify that THIS tile is a grass tile which must get THAT grass texture?
- How big can my textures be when I bind them to a texture unit?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I render different rectangles / quads with different textures?

You've got two choices:

1. Create a texture for each kind of tile (grassTex and rockTex) for example. Then when you draw your scene, bind the appropriate texture before drawing all the tiles of a certain type, e.g.

   ```
   glBindTexture(..., grassTex); 
   drawAllGrasstiles();
   glBindTexture(..., rockTex); 
   drawAllRocktiles();
   ```
2. Use what's known as a 'sprite sheet', in which you pack all your different textures in a grid into a larger texture. So you might have one texture, in which the left half of the texture is grass, and the right half of the texture is rock. Then you can draw all your grass and rock tiles together in the same batch, and you use the texture coordinates to differentiate which part of the texture is drawn. Now instead of all your tiles having texture coordinates from 0 to 1, they are from 0 to 0.5 for grass, and from 0.5 to 1.0 for rock.

> How big can my textures be when I bind them to a texture unit?

This is implementation dependent. Call glGet with `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` to query the implementation limit.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your feedback. I think I'll go for the sprite sheet idea, makes sense to avoid too many "bind" calls.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your biggest texture is 1024 x 1024 for maximum compatibility. 1024 is more than enough for and XBOX 360 and PS3 and should be more than enough for you :).

Also, I suggest you render the whole level in one pass and use just one texture with it. I don't see the trouble in that. Whether this one texture has water, rock and birds altogether or not it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. OK from the 2 answers it makes sense just to load one huge texture and index that with the vertex texture coords.